# Symmetry in Laplace PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am unable to understand the symmetry stated in my textbook, as below. Can someone please explain in detail?

> We want to find the PDF of Z=X-Y, assuming X and Y are independent and exponentially distributed random variables with parameter $\lambda$.
>
> First calculate CDF $F_Z(z)$ for z >=0. $F_Z(z)=P(X-Y<=z)=1-P(X-Y>z)$

which is calculated as $1-\frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{2}$

> For the case z<0, the symmetry of the situation implies that the random variable Z=X-Y and -Z=Y-X have the same distribution. We have $$F_Z(z)=P(Z<=z)=P(-Z>=-z)=P(Z>=-z)=1-F_Z(-z)$$

I am unable to understand here, how $P(-Z>=-z)=P(Z>=-z)$, and where is the symmetry. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same as to say

$$X-Y\dot{=}Y-X$$

and this is due to the fact that $X,Y$ are independent exponential with THE SAME PARAMETER.

To understand this symmetry do a drawing and calculate $P[(X-Y)<z_0]$ and $P[(Y-X)<z_0]$

Example: let's fix $z=z_0<0$

the area to be integrated in the two cases are the following

[image]

It think now the symmetry of the area is self evident and the fact that the two probabilities are also the same is evident too considering that $X,Y$ have the same exponential distribution.